# Data Loader: csv file with records without ID, instead with External ID

Tags: data-loader, update

I used the `upsert` function in Data Loader, but it created new records, not updated records. How can I update these records using an External ID instead of a Salesforce ID?

On the Lead object I have a text field and made it an External ID. It is not a lookup, it's just a text field. And I need to update records using this External Text field.

Comment: Please provide more details, what kind of data you are uploading, which object etc

Comment: Done. Adeed few details

Comment: Make sure that your field is marked as an "External ID", if so it should be visible. Please also remember that after you made this change in your org, you have re-launch data loader and once again log in to your org. Then you have to select your external id field as an "field for matching on Lead".

Comment: All of these is done. And doesnt help. Idk what is problem

Comment: In your import file, the data which is available in the text field and same data should be available in the salesforce records too then only those records will update otherwise it will create new records

Comment: If you have all of those settings done - Can you check if you have a correct permissions in your profile/permission set?

Comment: I'm sys admin. Can be a problem that these lead is converted?

Comment: It's interesting. I'm just checking step by step in org and data loader and below steps that I've made to allow me use new external id field:
1. Create text field in org, selected checkbox next to “External ID”
2. Re-launch dataloader and re-login to org, select Upsert
3. Select Lead object and csv file
4. Below “Select the field for matching on Lead:” I’ve selected my ExternalId__c field

Additional question: Are you using "Salesforce Inspector" plugin?

Comment: If lead is converted it dont wanna to update this lead. What can be problem?